# Как запустить css анимацию по клику через jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, анимация, css-animation

```js
$('.c').click(function() {
});
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="c"></div>
```

Comment: Если вам помог [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815582/220571), то отметьте, пожалуйста, его как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа). Или оставьте уточняющий комментарий, объяснящий почему именно он вам не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

На вашем примере, как-то так https://jsfiddle.net/mfvp73ce/10/
К существующему классу просто добавляем анимированный класс

```js
$('.c').click(function() {
  $('.c').addClass('b');
});
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.b {
  animation-name: anim;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="c"></div>
```

Comment: Имена классов довольно безлики, а так вообще ответ хороший.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Согласен, я так не именую и не рекомендую, просто сделал в том же стиле в котором задан вопрос.

Comment: Да это скорее не для вас, я для будущих читателей с поисковиков.

Comment: Как вариант, не плохо. Но не универсально. Например в слайдере, при перелистывании слайдов, анимация не срабатывает на ходу. Интересно было бы запустить ее именно по клику из скрипта

Comment: @Amsterdam Это ответ на конкретны вопрос. Если вас вопрос по слайдеру, задайте его отдельно с кодом в песочнице.